# How do I run a Javascript program from the terminal in visual studio using node.js? picture attached of issue I'm having

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I'm unable to execute my program from the terminal when creating the program in Visual Studio. However, when I use node from the terminal in Visual Studio Code, it works as intended. I want to use Visual Studio.

When I use the terminal in visual studio code (and not visual studio), it executes as intended and runs without issues. However, when I attempt to run the same basic node command in visual studio it gives me 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' errors. When I run node --version it give me the current version of node.js. I don't think it is a path issue, but maybe a visual studio configuration issue. Any help is appreciated.
[image: Initial error]
I'm on a windows machine and if I type 'where node' it gives me the full path to the folder containing the app i'm trying to run. I'm a bit lost.

Edit: here are additional pictures. I think the issue is the path takes me to the the folder, but not into the solution itself. For example when I do 'where node' it says "C:\Users\trent\source\repos\NodeConsoleApp1", but when i go to where app is actually located it is: "C:\Users\trent\source\repos\NodeConsoleApp1\NodeConsoleApp1".

[image: Shows full file path]

Then here's 'where node':
[image: Where node]

Comment: Can you please share file structure and package.json file details for getting better overview?

Comment: Try `npm install` I guess.

Comment: Are you sure the file is called `app.js` and is located in the directory `NodeConsoleApp1`? (node tells you that it is not able to find `app.js`)

Comment: I have updated the original post with the issues I'm having. I believe it is a path issue now that i've gone to the actual solution in file explorer. My question now would be how do I edit the path to enter the solution automatically instead of just entering the folder containing the solution.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Unrelated: I'd recommend setting File Explorer to always show file extensions. It's harder to understand what we're looking at without them. A textual tree formatted as monospace is even better.